# SimpleMembershipProvider in mobile app ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm trying to use SimpleMembershipProvider to manage the authentication process of my mobile application.

I generated the project using Mobile template, but this doesn't generated the same files of the Internet application template. It doesn't created the folder `Filters` with `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs` file and the `web.config`, `AccountController` and `AccountModel` are different.

Can I use SimpleMembershipProvider with mobile applications? If yes, how should I do this? If not, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SimpleMembershipProvider in your mobile application. [This article provides complete instructions](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/04/using-simplemembership-with-mobile.html) on how to do this and provide links to an example VS project that can be downloaded.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was able do do that using files from the Internet application template (like AccountController and AccountModel). I copied that to my project. Here are some links that were helpful: http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/jsrender.js http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx